# ¿Cómo solucionar este error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 0? También para java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

He mirado bastante y no he podido solucionar este error, ademas de que me he dado cuenta de que cuando le doy al botón guardar y si ya hay datos en `Jtable` que tenga el campo hora salida, este los borra cuando ingresa un estudiante nuevo.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 0  at
>   java.util.Vector.removeElementAt(Vector.java:561)     at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.removeRow(DefaultTableModel.java:462)
>     at Vista.Principal.boton_EliminarActionPerformed(Principal.java:518)
>     at Vista.Principal.access$900(Principal.java:14)    at
>   Vista.Principal$11.actionPerformed(Principal.java:287)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

```
String sistFecha=Fecha_Hora.Fecha();
String sistHora=Fecha_Hora.Hora(); 
Timer tiempo;
public boolean bien = false;//Para La Validacion De Ingreso De Datos
ArrayList<Estudiantes> datos_estudiantes= new ArrayList<Estudiantes>();
DefaultTableModel modelo= new DefaultTableModel();   
int filas;

public Principal() 
{
    initComponents();
    activar_desactivar(false,0);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Pantalla En El Centro
    //this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    jlFecha_Sistema.setText(sistFecha);//FECHA DEL SISTEMA
    //jlHora_Sistema.setText(sistHora);//HORA DEL SISTEMA    
    tiempo=new Timer(100, new Principal.horas());
    tiempo.start();
    this.jtable_Datos.setModel(modelo);
}

private void boton_GuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    validacion();
    if(bien==true)
    {
        Estudiantes estudiantes= new Estudiantes(sistFecha, txCodigo.getText(), txNombre.getText(), 
        cbCarrera.getSelectedItem().toString(), txHora_Ingreso.getText(), txHora_Salida.getText(), 
        cbSala.getSelectedItem().toString(), txServicio.getText(), cbMonitores.getSelectedItem().toString());
        datos_estudiantes.add(estudiantes);
        mostrar();
        activar_desactivar(false,0);
        limpiar_campos();
    }
}                                             

private void boton_EditarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        String []datos=new String[9];
        datos[0]=sistFecha;
        datos[1]=txCodigo.getText();
        datos[2]=txNombre.getText();
        datos[3]=cbCarrera.getSelectedItem().toString();
        datos[4]=txHora_Ingreso.getText();
        datos[5]=txHora_Salida.getText();
        datos[6]=cbSala.getSelectedItem().toString();
        datos[7]=txServicio.getText();
        datos[8]=cbMonitores.getSelectedItem().toString();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<jtable_Datos.getColumnCount();i++)
        {
            jtable_Datos.setValueAt(datos[i], filas, i);
        } 
        activar_desactivar(false,0);
}                                            

private void boton_EliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    int filaselecionada= jtable_Datos.getSelectedRow();
    System.out.println();
    if(filaselecionada>=0)
    {
        modelo.removeRow(filaselecionada); Aqui Es Dondel Señala el error
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Ha Seleccionado Ninguna Fila");
    }
}                                              

public void activar_desactivar(boolean desicion, int desicion2)
{
    txCodigo.setEnabled(desicion);
    txNombre.setEnabled(desicion);
    cbCarrera.setEnabled(desicion);
    txHora_Ingreso.setEnabled(desicion);
    if (desicion2==0){txHora_Salida.setEnabled(false);} 
    else {txHora_Salida.setEnabled(true);}
    cbSala.setEnabled(desicion);
    txServicio.setEnabled(desicion);
    cbMonitores.setEnabled(desicion);
    boton_Guardar.setEnabled(desicion);
    boton_Cancelar.setEnabled(desicion);
}

public void limpiar_campos()
{
    txCodigo.setText("");
    txNombre.setText("");
    cbCarrera.setSelectedIndex(0);
    txHora_Ingreso.setText("");
    txHora_Salida.setText("");
    cbSala.setSelectedIndex(0);
    txServicio.setText("");
    cbMonitores.setSelectedIndex(0);
}

private boolean validacion() 
{  
    int carrera = cbCarrera.getSelectedIndex();
    int sala = cbSala.getSelectedIndex();
    int monitores = cbMonitores.getSelectedIndex();

    if(txCodigo.getText().length() == 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese El Codigo","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }    
    else if(txNombre.getText().length() == 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese El Nombre","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }        
    else if(carrera==0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese La Carrera","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(txHora_Ingreso.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese La Hora de Llegada","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(sala==0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese La Sala","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(txServicio.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese El Servicio Utilizado","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else if(monitores==0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese El Monitor Que Lo Atendio","ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else
    {
        bien=true;
    }
    return bien;
}       

private void mostrar() 
{
    String matris[][]= new String[datos_estudiantes.size()][9];
    for (int i = 0; i < datos_estudiantes.size(); i++) 
    {
        matris[i][0]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getFecha();
        matris[i][1]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getCodigo();
        matris[i][2]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getNombre();
        matris[i][3]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getCarrera();
        matris[i][4]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getHora_Ingreso();
        matris[i][5]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getHora_Salida();
        matris[i][6]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getSala();
        matris[i][7]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getServicio();
        matris[i][8]= datos_estudiantes.get(i).getMonitores();
    }
    jtable_Datos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel
    ( matris, new String [] {"Fecha", "Codigo", "Nombre", "Carrera", "Hora Ingreso", 
                            "Hora Salida", "Sala", "Servicio", "Monitores", } ));
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. La primera cuestión : ¿Sabes que significa una `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Bienvenido John,puedes poner el track del error?

Comment: Juan la verdad soy algo nuevo en esto y no se lo que significa, y angel ya he puesto el track del error

Comment: @John Pelaez El error dice que estas accediendo a la posicion tres del array la cual no existe

Comment: En la función Mostrar() que tienes de ultimo puedes intentar escribir el código donde ingresas los nombres de las columnas antes de ingresar los datos a la tabla: Te digo esto ya que en mi experiencia programando tablas siempre se levanta la excepción, cuando intentaba introducir datos a la tabla antes de los nombres de las columnas. Investigando encontré que de esa forma se establecen los indices de la cantidad de columnas a utilizar. Espero le sirva a alguien

Answer (score 2):

Un primer paso para resolver problemas con excepciones es saber qué significa, y el [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) suele dar la primera aproximación:

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

También vemos en el Javadoc que `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` es una subclase, un caso especial de [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html), que dice:

> Thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.

Es decir, tienes una de estas porque tienes elementos ordenados por un índice de X a Y, pero estás intentando acceder a un índice Z que no está entre X e Y.

Es como poner en fila a cinco niños y que te pidan el nombre del niño que está el décimo en la fila. Obviamente es un error (o debería haber más niños, o el niño en el que están interesados es otro).

La `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` te indica que el error se da al acceder a un array. Un array tiene elementos entre 0 y [número de elementos del array - 1]. En este caso, el array está dentro de la implementación de `java.util.Vector` (se puede ver en el stacktrace).

El resto del mensaje `3 >= 0` te indica que intentas acceder al elemento en la posición `3` pero el array tiene `0` posiciones (básicamente, está vacío) así que lanza la excepción. No se puede obtener ningún elemento de un array vacío (lógicamente).

Una vez que sabes qué significa la excepción, eres tú quien debe corregir la causa del error (¿inicializar el array? ¿calcular el índice de otra forma?) de acuerdo con como debe funcionar tu programa.

Comment: Esta respuesta es una respuesta genérica para todas las preguntas con `IndexOutOfBoundException`s, explicando porqué se producen y qué hay que mirar de solucionar, aunque no entre en las causas concretas del fallo en tu programa.

Comment: En cuanto a tu programa, `modelo.removeRow` falla porque `modelo` no tiene datos (su longitud es 0). Como el `selectedRow` devuelve un valor mayor que 0, **es obvio que modelo NO es el *tablemodel* usado por tu tabla**, aunque lo asignes en el constructor). Si te fijas en `mostrar()`, allí estás creando un nuevo *tablemodel*, que es el que usa de verdad tu tabla y el que tiene los datos.

Comment: Mil Gracias a la Primer respuesta me re ayudó, GEEEENIO!!!

Comment: @Daniel si esta respuesta te sirvió, entonces ayudaría mucho le des un +1 y la marques como aceptada, es el mejor modo de agradecer a quien te respondió (@SJuan76 en este caso)